# Recursive unordered_map | is there a better way?

Tags: c++, struct, unordered-map

I am doing some random codes where I can think of a solution where I would need to use an `unordered_map<char, unordered_map<char,...>>`
**I know it looks weird**, and also how would you define something like that?

What I have done is used a declaration using `struct`

```
struct Node {
    unordered_map<char, Node*> n;
}
```

This kind of a recursion would end with an **empty *unordered_map***, (according to me)

Now using such a declaration costs a lot of weird looking code like:

```
void XYZ(Node *ptr){
    while (ptr->n[<key>].empty()){
        ptr = &ptr->n[<key>];
        // or do something
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**: Is there a better way to accomplish the same (maybe not using struct)?

Comment: Are you using map for checking whether a key exist or not, like a flag? If not what is the usage here?

Comment: Yes!!! it is kind of a Trie.

Comment: Yes, now that I think of it I should be using `unordered_map<char, Node*>`. But the question still remains... Is there a way to not use a **struct** at all. because the struct basically has only one member.

Comment: Since the container contains itself, you need the struct and the pointer to break the cyclic dependencies or whatever it should be called in this case. I would suggest using `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of a raw pointer though.